# How to force playing a video in fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, video, mobile, streaming

I need to know how it's possible to force playing a video in fullscreen mode?

Fullscreen is in most of the cases a function by ActionScript and is triggerd with a user action, like mouse click or double click.

The other way is to force playing a video in the mobile devices native player, like youtube does. I have no clue how this approach is realized.

Hope to understand this thing a bit more clearer with your support.

chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can tell the Flash stage to go to fullscreen view with this command:

```
stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
```

It will work in standalone mode only.

To make it work in the browsers you have to pass the "allowFullScreen" parameter with a "true" value to Flash.

To go fullscreen in mobile devices I believe you have to use the

`FSCommand("fullscreen", "true");` method call.

If you are using SWFObject the you can add the allowFullScreen param easily.

**SWFObject -2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var so = new SWFObject("movie.swf", "mymovie", "400", "400", "8", "#336699");
   so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
   so.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "sameDomain");
   so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
   so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

**SWFObject 2+:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wl = new Object();
wl.flashvars = {};
wl.params = {
    allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain",
    allowFullScreen: "true",
    wmode: "opaque"
};
wl.attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "flashcontent", "400", "400", "8", "swf/expressInstall.swf", wl.flashvars, wl.params, wl.attributes);
</script>
```

I hope it helps, good luck
Rob

Comment: Is there a way to pass these commands via javascript to the swf object? Currently I am using the video platform "brightcove". Once you have included your JS Code, you'll get a Video Stream to your device. Due it's forbidden force fullscreen, I was thinking about this approach. Question is the first sentence in this comment.

Comment: Hi, the short answer is definitely yes, see my updated answer.